# EF6 Include doesn't work

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a Book class and it has an Book Versions in child table. When I am fecthing the books , BookVersions aren't fetched but other related table are fetched. I know you will say after seeing source code 'where is the default constructor' but I tried to add it but it also doesn't work.

When I try to execute query manually, returns a BookVersion as expected.

Additional information:
 I am using MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.3 version, EF6

[image: Sample run]

Query to retrieve the 
data

SELECT
`Project1`.`Id`, 
`Project1`.`Name`, 
`Project1`.`AuthorName`, 
`Project1`.`AddedDate`, 
`Project1`.`Active`, 
`Project1`.`C1`, 
`Project1`.`Id1`, 
`Project1`.`VersionName`, 
`Project1`.`BookData`, 
`Project1`.`BookCover`, 
`Project1`.`Active1`, 
`Project1`.`BookId`
FROM (SELECT
`Limit1`.`Id`, 
`Limit1`.`Name`, 
`Limit1`.`AuthorName`, 
`Limit1`.`AddedDate`, 
`Limit1`.`Active`, 
`Extent2`.`Id` AS `Id1`, 
`Extent2`.`VersionName`, 
`Extent2`.`BookData`, 
`Extent2`.`BookCover`, 
`Extent2`.`Active` AS `Active1`, 
`Extent2`.`BookId`, 
CASE WHEN (`Extent2`.`Id` IS  NULL) THEN (NULL)  ELSE (1) END AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`, 
`Extent1`.`AuthorName`, 
`Extent1`.`AddedDate`, 
`Extent1`.`Active`
FROM `Books` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE 3 = `Extent1`.`Id` LIMIT 1) AS `Limit1` LEFT OUTER JOIN `BookVersions` AS `Extent2` ON `Limit1`.`Id` = `Extent2`.`BookId`) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`Id` ASC, 
`Project1`.`C1` ASC

-- Executing at 21.10.2014 09:22:41 +03:00

-- Completed in 14 ms with result: EFMySqlDataReader

SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`,
`Extent1`.`VersionName`, 
`Extent1`.`BookData`, 
`Extent1`.`BookCover`, 
`Extent1`.`Active`, 
`Extent1`.`BookId`
FROM `BookVersions` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE 3 = `Extent1`.`BookId` LIMIT 1

-- Executing at 21.10.2014 09:22:41 +03:00

-- Completed in 7 ms with result: EFMySqlDataReader

SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`Note`, 
`Extent1`.`StartDate`, 
`Extent1`.`ExpirationDate`, 
`Extent1`.`OwnUserId`, 
`Extent1`.`WhoGaveId`, 
`Extent1`.`BookId`
FROM `UserBooks` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`BookId` = @EntityKeyValue1

-- EntityKeyValue1: '3' (Type = Int32)

-- Executing at 21.10.2014 09:22:50 +03:00

-- Completed in 1 ms with result: EFMySqlDataReader

Source code is below:

```
public class Book : BaseEntity
{
    private ICollection<UserBook> _userBook;
    private ICollection<BookVersion> _bookVersions;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value Book name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating Book's author name
    /// </summary>
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating Book's added date
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the Book is active
    /// </summary>
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets who can see the Book
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks
    {
        get { return _userBook ?? (_userBook = new List<UserBook>()); }
        set { _userBook = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the versions of the Book
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<BookVersion> BookVersions
    {
        get { return _bookVersions ?? (_bookVersions = new List<BookVersion>()); }
        set { _bookVersions = value; }
    }
}

public class BookVersion : BaseEntity
{

    private Book _book;

    public BookVersion() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating VersionName
    /// </summary>
    public string VersionName { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Book Data.
    /// <remarks>It stores the File as Byte. It is a discrete form of the Book</remarks>
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] BookData { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating Book cover
    /// </summary>
    public byte[] BookCover { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the version is active
    /// </summary>
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating book identifier
    /// </summary>
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the version belongs to whom
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Book OfBook
    {
        get { return _book ?? (_book = new Book()); }
        set { _book = value; }
    }

}
```

Mappings are:

```
public class BookMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{

    public BookMapping()
    {

        this.HasKey(b => b.Id);

        this.Property(b => b.Name).HasMaxLength(255);
        this.Property(b => b.AuthorName).IsOptional();
        this.Property(b => b.AuthorName).HasMaxLength(255);
        this.Property(b => b.Name).IsRequired();
        this.Property(b => b.Active).IsRequired();

    }

}

public class BookVersionMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<BookVersion>
{

    public BookVersionMapping()
    {

        this.HasKey(n => n.Id);

        this.Property(n => n.BookData).IsRequired();
        this.Property(n => n.VersionName).IsRequired();
        this.Property(n => n.VersionName).HasMaxLength(255);
        this.Property(n => n.BookCover).IsOptional();

        this.HasRequired(bv => bv.OfBook).WithMany(b => b.BookVersions).HasForeignKey(bv => bv.BookId).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: You want to retrieve all related BookVersion rows when you select a Book row?  At the db layer, you want an inner join?  `var query = from book in context.Books.Include("BookVersions")` should get you there.

Comment: Are you sure the first book returned by your query has any `BookVersions`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure Michael. scott lazyloading is set true but I also tried as you said but it again doesn't work.

Comment: It will be an absurd but Can it be related with byte[] ? I think all configurations are true but that table is seperated others by only having byte[] type

Comment: Do you see BookVersions in the SQL query? Also, try to remove the part `?? (_book = new Book())`. Maybe this confuses relationship fixup.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't also work. I am also adding the Sql Query to question..